# SQL/Python3/6 UPDATE with LIKE and wildcard

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

How can I update mytable the value of "num" where the column "incident_id" is like "inc"

I have tried changing to LIKE '%%%S%%' but I get an error, what is the correct way?

```
num = "I-102930"
inc = "hdtff-dd24r-sdft4-sfgg"       

 cur = conn.cursor()
 num = str(inc_num)
 inc = inc_id
 sql = """ UPDATE mytable SET incident_num =%s WHERE incident_id LIKE %s """
 val = (num, inc)
 cur.execute(sql, val)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to use `?` placeholders for the parameters that you pass and in the query to concatenate the `'%'` wildcards:

```
sql = "UPDATE mytable SET incident_num = ? WHERE incident_id LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')"
val = (num, inc)
cur.execute(sql, val)
```

`CONCAT()` is MySql's way to concatenate strings.
A more general, database agnostic way would be to concatenate the wildcards to the variable `inc`:

```
sql = "UPDATE mytable SET incident_num = ? WHERE incident_id LIKE ?"
val = (num, "%" + inc + "%")
cur.execute(sql, val)
```